# Convert local IST time to unix timestamp using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I want to convert the following datetime into unix timestamp.

```
Tue Feb 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

How can I do so using *Moment.js*

Comment: What is the type of your input? JS Date or a string? To convert to unix timestamp use [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) or [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
var date = moment('Tue Feb 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)').unix();
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert to unix timestamp use [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) (milliseconds) or [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) (seconds).

If your input is a JavaScript Date, you can just use [`moment(Date);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/) (or simply use JS date `getTime()`).

If your input is a string you can parse it using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
var m = moment('Tue Feb 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss Z');
```

Here a working example:

```js
var d = new Date(2017, 1, 28);
console.log(moment(d).valueOf());
console.log(moment(d).unix());
var s = 'Tue Feb 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)';
var m = moment(s, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss Z');
console.log(m.valueOf());
console.log(m.unix());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```